# Word for something that can be expressed in currencies

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives, terminology

What may be a term (word, phrase or expression) to indicate that an object property (e.g. price, value) **is expressed in a specific currency**, something like "currenciable".

Similar example can be "translatable", as something that can  be expressed in a specific language/locale.

Comment: You should add more context to your question. Also, you should use the `word-request` or `phrase-request` tag. Avoid being marked off-topic or spam.

Comment: The way you word this makes me think your looking for something to fit the polymorphic naming convention in Ruby on Rails.  True?  In which case, I wouldn't worry about finding a 'proper' word for this.  Currenciable or monetizable would be understood by other programmers.

Comment: @BeulahAkindele sorry, thats my first question here, so i'm not familiar with the common best practices

Comment: @JohnFeltz it's not Ruby on Rails, but for a Laravel trait

Comment: You don't have to apologize, just a tip.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ***[monetizable](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/monetizable)***

From [monetize:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/monetize)

> to change something into money, or to express something in terms of money or a currency:
>
> - Japan is monetizing several trillion dollars of government debt.

(M -W)

Comment: If you agree with the answer, you should mark it as correct. A check mark should be grouped with the upvote and downvote buttons.